Show that $PLANAR \in co-NP \cap NP$
The fact that the language of planar graphs is in $co-NP$ is easy to show because the complexity of finding a Kuratowski subgraph is $O(|V|)$. But what about $NP$? Any help is appreciated.

"The complexity of finding a Kuratowski subgraph is $O(|V|)$" Could you elaborate?

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338115611_Simplified_On_Algorithms_for_Planar_Graph_Embedding_Kuratowski_Subgraph_Isolation_and_Related_Problems

To prove that a graph is planar, you "just" need to find a planar embedding.
De Fraysseix, Pach and Pollack showed that a planar graph with $n$ vertices can be embedded in a grid such that:

all vertices have integer coordinates in a $(2n-4)\times (n-2)$ grid;
all edges are straight lines;
no two edges cross.

Such an embedding is a $\mathsf{NP}$ certificate and is of polynomial size. It can be verified in polynomial time that no two edges cross.

Is their proof elementary?

No idea, I did not read the paper.
